# Filtering Nested Array with Javascript or Lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am trying to filter the projects that only contain `"isFavorite": true`.

```
temp1 = {
  "Name": "Toronto",
  "Area": [ 
    {
      "Title": "Roofing",
      "Details": {
        "Reports": 52,
        "Projects": [ 
          {
            "Name": "ITEM A",
            "isFavorite": true
          }, 
          {
            "Name": "ITEM B",
            "isFavorite": false
          }, 
          {
            "Name": "ITEM C",
            "isFavorite": true
          } 
        ]
      }
    } 
  ]
}
```

I tried using lodash filter function but the array returns everything.

```
_.filter(temp1, {Area: [{Projects: [{isFavorite: true}] }]});
```

I tried using regular javascript but still doesn't return only the projects that are `"isFavorite": true`

```
this.branchSummaries.filter(d => d.Area.some(p => p.Projects.some(f => f.isFavorite === true)));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need first to loop through the `Areas` after that filter `projects` in each `Area`
it would be like this

```js
 let data =  {
      "Name": "Toronto",
      "Area": [
        {
          "Title": "Roofing",
          "Details": {
            "Reports": 52,
            "Projects": [
              {
                "Name": "ITEM A",
                "isFavorite": true
              },
              {
                "Name": "ITEM B",
                "isFavorite": false
              },
              {
                "Name": "ITEM C",
                "isFavorite": true
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }

data.Area.forEach(area => {
  area.Details.Projects = area.Details.Projects.filter(project => project.isFavorite)
})
console.log(data)
```